# Unable To show the navigation bar when I do popViewControllerAnimated

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I am having two viewControllers , I am navigating from the FirstView to SecondView , by

pushing the SecondView to the navigation controller. Since I don't want the navigation bar

to be shown in the SecondView , I do the following

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
```

Then I move back from the, secondView to the FirstView as follows

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But now the navigation Bar is not shown in the FirstView as well since I am hiding it in the

SecondView.  I am trying to the following in the FirstView

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

       [super viewWillAppear:YES];

       self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=NO;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this instead:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You set initWithNib or viewDidLoad method and run it

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
      self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=NO;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Trying show the navigationBar before you pop the second view controller, like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=NO;
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

try it in the following method:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=NO;
}
```

but to me it should work in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 1):

Place the below code in the second view

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
```

}